# Meaning of "yield" in acrostic for 'pray'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Some people expand the word *pray* as an acronym for: **p**raise, **r**epent, **a**sk, **y**ield.

What does *yield* mean in this religious context?

```
Original wording of question was: "Some people expand the word pray to mean..."
```

Comment: I dare say that the religion tag is not required.

Comment: @Terry LiYifeng: I think your original question may have thrown some off, in that you said, "Some people expand the word "pray" **to mean**..."  Had you said "Some people expand the word "pray" as follows..." you might have been spared the diversions.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for pointing that out. Apologies for my poor English and the confusion caused by it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Yield* here refers to surrendering to God. This means allowing oneself to be led by the will of God.

Comment: See definition 3, 4 and 5 of [yield](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yield).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a letter-by-letter "expansion" of any "word"; this has nothing to do with the English language.

It's just a mnemonic for advertising or memorization, like

- *ΙΧΘΥΣ*
- *LS/MFT*
- *O Be A Fine Girl Kiss Me Now*.

Comment: -1 the question was about the meaning of the word yield used in context.

Comment: Its meaning is whatever its speaker intends it to mean, like the "F" in _LS/MFT_.

Answer (score 1):

It's not meant to be a definition of prayer; it's meant to be an acrostic mneumonic that serves as a rough guideline on how to pray.

You see these same elements in the Lord's prayer, where Jesus offers *praise* to God ("hallowed be thy name... for thine is the glory"); offers words of *repentance* ("forgive us our trespasses"); *asks* for sustainment ("give us this day our daily bread"); and offers *yielded* service ("thy will be done").

```
Not all prayer need follow this model, obviously...
```

Comment: I saw nothing that implied the questioner was equating the expansion to a definition of prayer.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: No, but he did inquire about the "religious context..."

Answer (score 1):

yield here means `to surrender` as in `yield to` i.e. surrender to someone/something.

usage: He yielded himself to temptation. [[ref]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yield)